# Kubernetes Ingress routing by service label

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

Is it possible to route Ingress requests based on service labels instead of a service name?

I would like to have 2 services with the same name but different label values.
Can Ingress route traffic like this?

```
service-name.labelA.com -> service with label = A
service-name.labelB.com -> service with label = A
```

Is it possible to do so?
Because in the [Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) it uses routing by service name and port (no labels):

```
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Am I right that you'd like to:
1) run multiple services with the same name but different selectors;
2) receive traffic to service-name.labelA.com and service-name.labelB.com and pass it to 2 different services (same name, just different selectors) ?

it would be good if you can provide an output of  'kubectl get service -o wide' and 'kubectl get ingress'

Comment: @PjoterS yes you are right. 
I've added example of configuration from the docs. But it only uses serviceName and servicePort. Is is possible to use labels here?
And is it even possible to have 2 services with the same name in single namespace (but different labels)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes won't let you creating two services with the same name

```
$ cat service_A.yaml apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: portfwd-srv-a 
spec: 
  ports: 
    - 
      nodePort: 30010
      port: 88
      name: knp1
  selector: 
    app: nginx
  type: NodePort

cat service_B.yaml apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: portfwd-srv-a 
spec: 
  ports: 
    - 
      nodePort: 30011
      port: 88
      name: knp1
  selector: 
    app: nginx
  type: NodePort

$ kubectl create -f service_A.yaml 
service/portfwd-srv-a created

$ kubectl create -f service_B.yaml 
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "service_B.yaml": services "portfwd-srv-a" already exists

$  kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE    SELECTOR
kubernetes           ClusterIP   10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP                      6d3h   <none>
portfwd-srv-a        NodePort    10.0.5.233   <none>        88:30010/TCP                 3m     app=nginx
web                  NodePort    10.0.4.73    <none>        8080:31881/TCP               3d     run=web
```

However, it is possible to target the same service (or any service of your choice with the Ingress).
The example below is influenced  by the [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting) documentation.

```
$ cat ingress_namebased.yaml 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: name-virtual-host-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: web
          servicePort: 8080
  - host: bar.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: web
          servicePort: 8080
```

here I'm serving requests sent to `foo.bar.com` and `bar.foo.com` with the `web` service:

```
$ kubectl get ingress 
NAME                        HOSTS                     ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
name-virtual-host-ingress   foo.bar.com,bar.foo.com   35.186.*.*      80      134m

$ kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)               AGE    SELECTOR
web        NodePort    10.0.4.73    <none>        8080:31881/TCP        3d     run=web
...
```

that points to a few pods/end_points:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP          NODE                    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
web-ddb799d85-7x2v4      1/1     Running   0          3d      10.12.0.6   cluster-1-pool-1-6v3n   <none>           <none>
web-ddb799d85-p2cq8      1/1     Running   0          2d21h   10.12.1.8   cluster-1-pool-1-m7z8   <none>           <none>

$ kubectl get ep -o wide
NAME                 ENDPOINTS                       AGE
web                  10.12.0.6:8080,10.12.1.8:8080   3d
```

and here the example of how it works from "end user" prospective ( round robin because I have 2 end points ):

```
$ curl foo.bar.com
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-ddb799d85-7x2v4

$ curl foo.bar.com
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-ddb799d85-p2cq8

curl bar.foo.com
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-ddb799d85-p2cq8

$ curl bar.foo.com
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-ddb799d85-7x2v4
```